# In order to Verb and (to) Verb

Tags: infinitives, parallelism, conjunction-reduction

> In order to  address traffic jam and reduce carbon footprint
>
> In order to  address traffic jam and **to** reduce carbon footprint

Which one is correct?

Comment: The *to* frequently gets eluded, so they are both correct in that sense. However *traffic jam* should be in the plural, and *carbon footprint* needs either a *the* or an *our* in front of it.

Comment: These are preposition phrases, not full sentences. The second subordinator "to" is freely omissible in such coordinations.

Comment: To me (as a Brit), there are two worse things wrong with your sentences: I would say "In order to address traffic jam***s*** and (to) reduce ***the*** carbon footprint".  If English is not your first language, you may find or sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, neither of them is incorrect.  However, the first one is less wordy, sounds better, and is the one many people would choose.  While using the additional preposition "to" in the second one creates a sense of parallelism in the phrase, the second "to" is not necessary.  I would say the first choice is the better one!

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! We strive to provide objective and well-researched answers. Please could you expand and provide evidence to improve this answer. Take the [Tour] and see [answer] for more.